# Why cabal build fails if cabal file changed?

Tags: haskell, cabal

Someone help me make sense of it. Cabal, great app, love it. But cabal build will fail if the cabal file has changed, with a message saying run cabal configure. It does not complain about this on cabal install though. I don't understand why programmers of cabal went to all the trouble to detect the situation and put the message out instead of running the configure step automatically. Why?

Comment: Actually not a bad question, but I am sure that there is a reason. I just use cabal install all the time anyway and send stuff to my local .cabal folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I actually think this has changed in cabal-install 0.9.5 and Cabal 1.10.1.0:

```
$ cabal unpack bytestring
cd byteDownloading bytestring-0.9.1.9...
    Unpacking to bytestring-0.9.1.9/

$ cd bytestring-0.9.1.9/

$ runghc Setup.hs configure
Configuring bytestring-0.9.1.9...

$ touch bytestring.cabal 

$ runghc Setup.hs build
./bytestring.cabal has been changed. Re-configuring with most recently used
options. If this fails, please run configure manually.
Configuring bytestring-0.9.1.9...
Preprocessing library bytestring-0.9.1.9...
Building bytestring-0.9.1.9...
[1 of 8] Compiling Data.ByteString.Fusion ( Data/ByteString/Fusion.hs, dist/build/Data/ByteString/Fusion.o )
... etc ...
```

So just wait for the next Haskell Platform release (with GHC 7 and the new Cabal) and you won't get this annoying error again :-)

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because this would lead to strange errors. Let's assume, you configured with some parameter, eg. you selected another compiler eith `-w`. Currently, cabal don't knows, what parameters you gave to the configuration. I guess it's actually smarter to request a reconfiguration instead of configuration with the default parameters instead. But why not open a ticket for this?